# How to index elements of a tuple in Django template using a variable?

Tags: python, django

I have `week_infos` tuple and pass it to template

```
{{ week_infos.4.0 }}
```

This works. However the following does not:

```
{% for j in 7|get_range %}
    <td row={{j}} col={{i|add:6}}>
        {{  week_infos.j }}
```

How can I access a specific item item in a tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the range in order to number your rows, however, you can do the same thing using a [for loop's counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for) if you loop over the week_infos tuple:

```
{% for week_info in week_infos %}
    <td row="{{ forloop.counter0 }}" col="{{ i|add:6 }}">
        {{ week_info }}
```

(Also, you should always wrap HTML attributes in quotes since they can contain spaces)